# iOS custom init issue, how to set the default init method?

Tags: ios, swift, init

I have a custom UILabel class.

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel{


    init(_ title: String = "Star"){
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        text = title
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        fatalError("Not Implemented")
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("Not Implemented")
    }


}
```

It is OK that I call like this

```
let head = CustomLabel("Front")
```

Not OK that I call like this

```
let lhs = CustomLabel()
```

Xcode reports : Not Implemented, and the program stops at here.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
     fatalError("Not Implemented")
}
```

Obviously `let lhs = CustomLabel()` call the method  `override init(frame: CGRect) {`,

How to make the `init(_ title: String = "Star"){` default?

ie. let Xcode find it first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the other init that you implemented and set yours as required

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {

    required init(_ title: String = "Star"){
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        text = title
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

let label1 = CustomLabel()
print(label1)
```

This works and uses the expected init

**EDIT:**

Bastian provided a useful link in their answer but has since removed it.

The link: [Adding Swift Convenience Initializers](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/adding-swift-convenience-initializers/)

Useful snippet from link (in case the link ever breaks):

> **Designated or Convenience?**
>
> First a recap on the two types of initializer:
>
> A designated initializer is the primary initializer for a class. It
>   must fully initialize all properties introduced by its class before
>   calling a superclass initializer. A class can have more than one
>   designated initializer.
>
> A convenience initializer is a secondary initializer that must call a
>   designated initializer of the same class. It is useful when you want
>   to provide default values or other custom setup. A class does not
>   require convenience initializers.
>
> **The Three rules**
>
> With that clear you need to remember three rules for designated and
>   convenience initializers for class types:
>
> - A designated initializer must call a designated initializer from the
>     immediate superclass.
> - A convenience initializer must call another
>     initializer from the same class.
> - A convenience initializer must
>     ultimately call a designated initializer.
>
> What does this mean for us?
>   In simple terms, do not call super from your convenience initializer.
>   Call another initializer (convenience or designated) from the same
>   class.

Comment: Hi, I have saw the documentation before I asked the question. I want to know the connection between the snippet with your answer. How you know `init(frame: CGRect) {` could be deleted, sounds like that it is a convenience method.

Comment: That is the default designated initializer for the UILabel, but if you subclass you can provide your own designated initializer that will then call super.init